# adding time out to blur custom directive in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Being new to angular JS have no idea whatsoever regarding how custom directives are written.
I want to write a custom directive for blur event with timeout included .
So far what I have found is

```
myCustomDirectives.directive(
[
    'blur',        
].reduce(function (container, name,$timeout) {
        $timeout(function(){
            var directiveName = 'custom' + name[ 0 ].toUpperCase() + name.substr(1);
            container[ directiveName ] =
                [
                    '$parse',
                    function ($parse) {
                        return function (scope, element, attr) {
                            var fn = $parse(attr[ directiveName ]);
                            element.bind(name,
                                function (event) {
                                    scope.$apply(function () {
                                        fn(scope,
                                            {
                                                $event: event
                                            });
                                    });
                                });
                        };
                    }
                ];
            return container;
        },4000);

    },
    { }));
```

It's a fairly complex code and can make no sense out of it trid enclosing it all in $timeout but it's not working .
If anyone could help me out figuring how to write on(custom directive i.e) for the above scenario , or just what am doing wrong would be obliged.

below is the partial code

```
<div class="form-row" ng-class="{'styled_forms error':emailAddressEmpty}">

    <input ng-model=".emailAddress" type="email" att-ignore-type id="billEmailAdd" class="span3" name="billEmailAdd"
           att-blur=validateBillingEmailAddress(); "/>
    <div class="alert-error form-row" role="tooltip"
         id="tooltipContent7" ng-class='{"error-alert":  emailAddressEmpty}' >
        <div class="popover-content" emailAddressEmpty ">
                                   <span tabindex="0">
                                        <span >Please enter an email address</span>
                                    </span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn " ng-click="cancelLink()" >cancel</button>
```

Comment: I really don't get what you are trying to archive... If you simply want to blur a DOM element after 4 seconds, your code would be 1/5 of it... Can you explain what you want to archive with it?

Comment: i basically have validations that need to performed on blur but then there's a cancel button on page on clicking of which the user should be redirected to start of the flow.however when i click on cancel I get validation error first and on second click ng-click get's executed as ng-blur overrides ng-click  .Hence want to delay blur event so that ng-click can get executed in the mean time.
Tried using ng-mousedown but with that too am able to see validation error messages before the ng-mousedown is performed

Comment: well that seems to me like you are using the wrong approach. I am sorry, but I don't get any particular use-case where this is needed. Can you give me an example? Then we can perhaps find a better way to solve it...

Comment: like there's page where a user can enter any information say his email ID now there are certain validations on that input feild for example valid email format etc which execute on blur event .Also there is a cancel button which takes the user to previous field.
Now if focus on the input field first and then click on the cancel button I get an error message as blur event overrides onclick event . However I don't want that .If a user clicks on cancel he/she should be redirected back and the validation should not happen.

Comment: you can always disable them and then executive a validation manually at an appropriate point later

Comment: didn't get you disable the validations?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you should get these validation errors when entering your email into the field. If your cancel-button triggers a submit, then your form setup is wrongly designed, so I would say... Can you edit your answer to contain the html form?

Comment: have added the partial example
Hope it helps understanding

Comment: I see no problem with it. Where is your cancel button in the code?

Comment: below the div
   <button type="button" class="btn " ng-click="cancelLink()" >cancel</button>

Comment: Yeah but I really do not get where the button throws validation errors? I would suggest you to make a jsfiddle with all your code...

Comment: the button doesn't ng-click doesn't get executed if the cursor is inside input div.
ng-blur get's executed for the first time as it takes precedence over ng-click

Comment: Then what about using the "tampered" flag when validating email address? So that validation is only executed after typing in something?

Comment: this was just an example of one of the validations I have 
there are other fields with other validations like can only be a number etc.

Comment: will using timeout delay the blur execution by some time???

Comment: The problem is, I have no information on the flow of your form, don't know your design and not even do I have a throughout understanding of your problem. I could guess what is wrong. Maybe something in your Javascript is not the way you want, maybe your validation error div hides the cancel button. But there are different solutions to different problems, please give me enough information to even understand what is going wrong...

Comment: If you really need a timeout so badly, put it in your ValidateBillingEmailAdress function and save you the hassle...

Comment: I could do that but that would mean adding timeout everywhere.
I thought adding timeout in the directive itself would be an easy solution. Guess not

Comment: Just out of curiosity who wouldn't adding timeout in the custom directive work ? The directive is working as expected without it>
Have I included it in a wrong way?

Comment: to be honest, no idea. Check your console first for errors. Have you "imported" timeout in your declaration, because i think it is missing its dependency declaration

Comment: have included timeout in dependency declaration.
No errors in console although while debugging in browser it gives me
uncaught TypeError:number can not be a function

Comment: That is somewhere different... Without the full site, no idea whats wrong, sorry

Comment: No problem .
Thanks for being so patient guess I should pick up angular js book and get my concepts clear

Comment: http://ngtutorial.com/learn/directive